# Getting DATEPART in HQL or Criteria?

Tags: nhibernate, datetime, hql, criteria

How can i get DATEPART of a time using HQL or Criteria ?
I have googled it up and get some tips, but wasn't enough.
If there is someone who has experienced it before, please let us know.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this post about [using sql functions in nhibernate](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2006/10/01/UsingSQLFunctionsInNHibernate.aspx) from ayende.

**EDIT** I have had success with something like this in the configuration file :

```
<property name="query.substitutions">
   true 1, false 0, yes 'Y', no 'N',getdate=getdate
</property>
```

notice the getdate=getdate, not sure how recommended this is but it is using the sql function :).

More on this : http://www.hibernate.org/hib_docs/nhibernate/html/session-configuration.html , search for query.substitutions.

Comment: Thank you,
I will check it as soon as possible