# Delete where record field < getdate()

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, date, sql-delete

I'm having trouble figuring out how to delete a set of records when a particular field is less than the date **on the sql server** without using tables or field names.

Since I'm using MSSQL the query would look something like this:

```
DELETE FROM tickets WHERE expires < getdate()
```

How would I go about getting Hibernate to do this? I'm looking into HQL but I don't see a way to specify `getdate()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably define a named SQL query:

```
<sql-query name="DeleteExpiredTickets">
 DELETE FROM tickets WHERE expires < getdate()
</sql-query>
```

Then call:

```
session.getNamedQuery("DeleteExpiredTickets").executeUpdate();
```

Comment: I may do it this way. Where does this go in the config file?

Comment: If you're using hbms you need to add it in the same way as a class mapping. Just replace the class definition with the code above and you're set.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use query.substitutions configuration. Take a look at this post and links in the answer:

[Getting DATEPART in HQL or Criteria?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/435645/getting-datepart-in-hql-or-criteria/435720)